# How to get the data from Sqlite database using cordova plugin in android?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using cordova plugin for insert,update and retrieve the data from sqlite local database. 
My database is manually placed inside the assets folder. Now I can able to insert and update the data in this database. But I can't able to retrieve the data. How can I fetch the data from this database into show my UI controls? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you can write to the db tables, you can also select from it. fter doin your SELECT query, you have to setup a callback function with "result" data set as stated in docs and read data from it. it's an object with dataset row you can parse. [manual paragraph on SQLResultSet object](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLResultSet)